# Regular Expression to select part in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have requirement to extract meta property from scrolled HTML source code. After scrolling HTML code contains as follows

**Example:**

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="asasasas">
<meta property="og:title" content="asajhskajhsaksp;" /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="images.cxs.com/2014/09/modit1.gif?w=209" />
```

Here I want to get the content of only where meta `property="og:image"` ie result should be only

> images.cxs.com/2014/09/modit1.gif?w=209

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Comment: @Biffen: What's wrong with using regex for this kind of task? There's no recursion or anything regex can't deal with.

Comment: @Rawing—HTML is not a regular language, it can't be reliably parsed with a regular expression, though you might use regular expressions to tokenise input in an HTML parser.

Comment: @Rawing Did you read the answer of the link? What if `property` and `content` are in the reverse order? What if there's some other attribute in there? What if there's a commented-out `meta` element somewhere? What if there's a HTML element in an attribute? I could go on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Biffen said, don't use regex to parse html.

If you have the said string in a variable you can use querySelector() like

```js
var html = '<meta property="og:site_name" content="asasasas" /><meta property="og:title" content="asajhskajhsaksp;" /><meta property="og:image" content="images.cxs.com/2014/09/modit1.gif?w=209" />';
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = html;
var meta = el.querySelector('meta[property="og:image"]');
console.log(meta.content);

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = meta.content;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

---

If it is part of the current page then

```js
var meta = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:image"]');
console.log(meta.content);

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = meta.content;
```

```html
<meta property="og:site_name" content="asasasas"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="asajhskajhsaksp;" /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="images.cxs.com/2014/09/modit1.gif?w=209" />

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @Arun,                                                           I am using CURL to crawl website first and store it in file.     
$ch = curl_init ($url);
$fp = fopen ($file, "w") or die("Unable to open ".$file." for writing.\n");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_close ($ch);
fclose ($fp);                                                        Now i have HTML code in that file .. So next can i go ahead like how you have suggested above right..  Or is there any other way to get contents of website other than CURL. Bcoz CURL crawls whole page but i want only HEAD section of HTML..

Answer (score 3):

was it so difficult to use jquery

```
$('meta[property="og:image"]').attr('content')
```

Comment: There is no jQuery tag or mention of it in the OP.

Comment: There was a mention of javascript, so I thought that a jquery solution may also suffice

Answer (score 0):

You can use the approach suggested by Arun, however there may be user agents that don't support the [*Selectors API*](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api2/) or don't support the required features (e.g. IE8). In that case, you can use [*getElementsByTagName*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-A6C9094) and a plain old for loop.

```
var node, nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
for (var i=0, iLen=nodes.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  node = nodes[i];

  if (node.getAttribute('property') == 'og:image') {

    // do something with content
    console.log(node.content);
  } 
}
```

the above will work in any browser in use and doesn't require any external library.